# Data does not appear in Elasticsearch using Kafka Elasticsearch Connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I'm building a simple chat app to practice my abilities with Kafka and Elasticsearch. I'm using [Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/)'s Kafka and its included [Kafka Connect Elasticsearch Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) as well as the open source version of [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). Communications between my app and Kafka use the [Kafka-rest API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html) with JSON. I am following the instructions [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/elasticsearch_connector.html).

As the instructions state, I am running Elasticsearch before I start the rest of the process. So far I am able to send messages from the app to Kafka and back again with no problem. When I run `confluent load elasticsearch-sink` after sending messages, I get the output the instructions say to expect. I don't get that output if I haven't sent the messages, which seems to indicate that the flow of data is working at least that far. However, when I cURL with the following command, which the docs state should get my data from Elasticsearch...

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/jsontest/_search?pretty'
```

...I get the following output...

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

...which does not include my messages. The data should be in `hits.hits`.

Please note that I am using version 5.6.8 of Elasticsearch, as the Confluent docs state that there is a known issue with versions 6.x. Also, my cURL command differs slightly from the example to account for the fact that my topic is `jsontest`, not `test-elasticsearch-sink`. I have been sure to change the topics in the `quickstart-elasticsearch.properties` file in order for this to work.

How do I get my data into Elasticsearch?

Comment: How did you verify that connect is actually running and has not failed its tasks? The docs are using `kafka-avro-console-producer`, and your topic is `jsontest`, so that's confusing.

Comment: As I mention in the question, I verify that connect is running because I get the output that the instructions say I should expect if messages have been sent. If no message have been sent, then there is no output. So some data is reaching it in some form to account for that discrepancy.

Yes, the instructions for the connector itself use Avro instead of JSON, but this shouldn't be an issue as those are just two ways of communicating with Kafka itself. My app sends messages to Kafka and then renders those same messages sent back from Kafka, so the success of that connection is not in doubt.

Comment: `confluent load elasticsearch-sink` only outputs the config for the task. Not the **health** of it, after trying to read any data from the actual topic.   Also, JSON message needs to follow a very specific format of a `schema` and `payload` fields for Connect to work with them. And if you are going to be using JSON, then you need to alter the worker properties to not use the Avro deserializers.

Comment: Parts 1 & 2 of this blog show MySQL to ElasticSearch. https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/  You could try to replace MySQL with whatever other source connector you wish, but I think your issue here is with the properties file of `elasticsearch-sink`, which you should add to the question